# Select full word in iTerm2 using alt + shift + arrow

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

Following [this advice](https://web.archive.org/web/20130918152133/http://blog.mattrevell.net/2013/06/07/iterm2-keybindings-for-os-x/), I've configured [**Iterm2**](https://www.iterm2.com/) to delete the word when <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I would like to build a similar functionality for combinations of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> **|** <kbd>→</kbd>. With respect to those combinations, I would like to be able to select word *behind* or *after* the cursor and expand the selection further by pressing the <kbd>←</kbd> **|** <kbd>→</kbd>  keys.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to `Preferences` then `Keys`.

Press the `+`.

For the `Keyboard Shortcut`, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd>

For <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, choose "Move Start of Selection Back" and "Move by Word".

[image]

For <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>, choose "Move End of Selection Forward" and "Move by Word".

[image]

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I can't delete the whole word after I get a weird symbol